# recaptcha v2 not getting the "success"

Tags: recaptcha

I’m having trouble in the implementation of recaptcha v2 chekbox. I first implemented in my form and it only works in local server. After failing in many attempts I search for some code and I’m using it raw from the tutorial and keep getting error. 
Url: https://afrumex.com/google_reCAPTCHA/prueba.html
Hope someone could help. Thanks!!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Ajax Contact Form</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- ajax contact form -->
<section style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header">Ajax Contact Form</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form class="contact__form" method="post" action="mail.php">

                            <!-- form message -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="contact__msg" style="display: none">
                                        <p>Your message was sent successfully.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end message -->

                            <!-- form element -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                    <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 form-group">

                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key here"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send Message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end form element -->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // access
    $secretKey = 'my secret key here';
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form1.</p>';
      exit;
    }

    # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
    $mail_to = "demo@gmail.com";

    # Sender Data
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
        # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please complete the form and try again.</p>';
        exit;
    }

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form2.</p>';
    } else {
        # Mail Content
        $content = "Name: $name\n";
        $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
        $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        # email headers.
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        # Send the email.
        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-success">Thank You! Your message has been sent.</p>';
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Something went wrong, we couldnt send your message.</p>';
        }
    }

} else {
    # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">There was a problem with your submission, please try again.</p>';
}
```

?>

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get the responce "success" so I get the "Please check the the captcha form2"

Comment: instead of using an alert with 'Please check the the captcha form2' just `console.log($response)` to debug

Comment: sorry didn't work : ( That only replace the message error to nothing. The trouble is that the respoce from google when the recaptcha is send is success==false

Comment: do you know how to debug the web? using Developer Tools? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ the Console and Network (if you know what your network call looks like) are useful

Comment: Thank you but I think isn't a problem with the code. I had tried a lot of ways even many tutorials an none of them work to me. Now i'm thinking maybe the ssl I have from let's encypt is no compatible with recaptcha. I'm searching for some info. Do you know something about that?(Sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I posted my solution under [the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297861/validate-recaptcha-ajax-and-codeigniter/54318743#54318743).

My tested solution is:

```
$google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$secret_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';

$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; 

$message  = 'Google reCaptcha Test';

if(!empty($response))
{
    $url = $google_url."?secret=".$secret_key."&response=".$response;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE); 
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $res = json_decode($curlData, TRUE);
    if($res['success'] == 'true') 
        $message = "Success!";
    else
        $message = "Enter captcha again!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a while trying to implement checkbox recaptcha v2 in my form, I tried to implement invisible recaptcha v2, and this one works perfectly. I don’t know how this can happen! You can see in function [here](https://www.afrumex.com/fruit.html#footer).

I don't know if it has something to do with my ssl certificate (from let's encrypt).

This [tutorial](https://www.pinnacleinternet.com/installing-invisible-recaptcha/) help me a lot.

Thanks for the comments [ehacinom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2553191/ehacinom)!!