# Validate recaptcha ajax and codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, recaptcha

I am using Codeigniter and Ajax to validate and submit the email form.
I tried many methods, it keeps giving me the result {"sent":false} it was working great before I add the recaptcha lines.

here is my code:

**custom.script.js**

```
$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
    var href = 'http://localhost:8888/en/send';
    var name = $("#form-name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var title = $("#form-title").val();
    var message = $("#form-message").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: href ,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            title: title,
            message: message,
            //UPDATE from recaptcha without quotes to 'g-recaptcha-response'
            'g-recaptcha-response': grecaptcha.getResponse()
          },

        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg.sent) {
                console.log("Successssssssssss");
                $('#result').addClass('success'); 
                $('#result').html('Email was sent successfully!');
            } else {
                $('#result').addClass('error'); 
                $('#result').html('Email was NOT sent!'); 
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**En.php**

```
function send()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    //UPDATE from recaptcha to 'g-recaptcha-response'
    $str = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
    $secret = 'GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY';
    $url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$str;
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);      
    $status= json_decode($output, true);


    if ($status['success']) {


    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $body    = 'ANY TEXT';
    $emailto = "email@domain.com";

    $this->email->from($this->input->post("email"), $this->input->post("name"));
    $this->email->to($emailto);
    $this->email->subject('New Request');
    $this->email->message($body);

    if($this->email->send()){
    echo json_encode(array("sent"=>TRUE));
    }

}
else{
    echo json_encode(array("sent"=>FALSE));
}}
```

The google keys are correct, I don't know why it is not getting to the true 
 if statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'g-recaptcha-response' and $status['success'] returns null in your given implementation, it might be better to use the method of cURL request as below:

```
$google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$secret_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';

$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; 

$message  = 'Google reCaptcha Test';

if(!empty($response))
{
    $url = $google_url."?secret=".$secret_key."&response=".$response;

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE); 
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $res = json_decode($curlData, TRUE);
    if($res['success'] == 'true') 
        $message = "Success!";
    else
        $message = "Enter captcha again!";
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm :) Thank you

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you. It is also wonderful to see those feedbacks here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello let's discuss this. It seems that returned data **$status['success']** needs to compare with a required values using "==" operator. You can check it like this.

```
if ($status['success'] == true) {


$this->load->library('email');

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$body    = 'ANY TEXT';
$emailto = "email@domain.com";

$this->email->from($this->input->post("email"), $this->input->post("name"));
$this->email->to($emailto);
$this->email->subject('New Request');
$this->email->message($body);

if($this->email->send()){
echo json_encode(array("sent"=>TRUE));
}
```

}

Also please distinguish the values before putting it on condition (if else statement).

Comment: Hey, is `$status['success']` has returning any value?

Comment: it never got into that if statement, I just saw many people using it I still don't know what it turns I will try to check

Comment: You must check that if statement. Because as you said on your post, you are getting `"sent"=>FALSE` so it means the code flows it did not accept the condition of your if statement.

Comment: it is returning: null

Comment: Even after submitting the form and marking the recaptcha it's still null

Comment: You can check if the file is sending $_POST values to your php file.

If you are using chrome then you can press F12, under Network tab and find XHR. There are more information about the errors you might have.

Comment: name: TEST
email: admin@123.com
phone: 1341234
title: 31242314
message: 1234432

Comment: it is not sending the recaptcha

Comment: Ok, I used "g-recaptcha-response" instead of "recaptcha" and it worked I could post the recaptcha response but the $status keeps returning null

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked this is the final code:

```
function send()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');


$google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$str = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');



$secret = 'GOOGLE SECRET KEY';
$url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$str;


$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
if ($response["success"] != false) {




    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $body    = 'ANY TEXT';

    $emailto = "email@domain.com";

    $this->email->from($this->input->post("email"), $this->input->post("name"));
    $this->email->to($emailto);

    $this->email->subject('New Request');
    $this->email->message($body);

    if($this->email->send()){
    echo json_encode(array("sent"=>TRUE));
    }
}
    else{
    echo json_encode(array("sent"=>FALSE));
     }
    }
```